# curl with variables

Tags: curl

The following outputs only one item.

```
SEARCH_URL="http://91.132.145.114/json/stations/search"

curl -X POST -d 'tag=jazz' -d 'language=english' -d 'state=queensland' "$SEARCH_URL"
```

But when I have the exact value in a variable, it outputs differently. It seems it ignores `-d` and outputs a lot.

```
SEARCH_URL="http://91.132.145.114/json/stations/search"
# parse options and store them in OPTS
# OPTS is something like this. 
OPTS="-d 'tag=jazz' -d 'language=english' -d 'state=queensland'"
curl -X POST "$OPTS" "$SEARCH_URL"
```

How can I make it work?
And why it is not working?

Comment: Remove the quotes from "$OPTS". I believe it should be enough. By using these quotes you're instructing your shell to consider everything a single argument (kind of ignoring the spaces). Not sure if I'm being clear enough...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double-quotes around `"$OPTS"` prevents the contents of the variable from being split on white-space, so it's treated as **one** argument to curl.  In other words, it's the same as running:

```
curl -X POST "-d 'tag=jazz' -d 'language=english' -d 'state=queensland'" "$SEARCH_URL"
```

Use an array instead.  For example:

```
SEARCH_URL="http://91.132.145.114/json/stations/search"

OPTS=(-d 'tag=jazz' -d 'language=english' -d 'state=queensland')
curl -X POST "${OPTS[@]}" "$SEARCH_URL"
```

That will cause **each element** of the OPTS array to be interpolated into the `curl` command line as if it were a separate quoted string - which is especially useful if the element contains, e.g., whitespace characters.

BTW, when parsing your options, you can add new elements to an array like:

```
OPTS+=(newoption)
```

or

```
OPTS+=(-d 'foo=bar')    # add two new elements: '-d' and 'foo=bar'
```

Comment: BTW, back in the bad old days before bash and other bourne-like shells gained arrays, it wasn't uncommon to build up a string variable containing command-line options as you did, and then use it unquoted (so that the shell would word-split it).  This mostly worked in many cases, but there were numerous flaws and problems with this approach, especially if any of those options contained whitespace characters or shell meta-characters.  Arrays solve these problems.