# Bash variable with curl

Tags: curl

When I run the following, it works and returns one item.

[online](https://reqbin.com/c-nbczl496)

```
curl -X POST -d 'tag=jazz' -d 'state=queensland' http://all.api.radio-browser.info/json/stations/search
```

But in a Bash script, when I use `-d 'tag=jazz' -d 'state=queensland'` for RES, I get different outputs.

```
read -rp "Write your quiry " RES
    echo "$RES"
    curl -X POST "$RES" http://all.api.radio-browser.info/json/stations/search
```

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
curl -X POST http://all.api.radio-browser.info/json/stations/search <<EOF
    "$RES"
EOF
```

How can I use a variable in a Bash script?

Comment: You can try `-d "'tag=jazz'"`.

Comment: Isn't this just a repeat of [curl with variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656916/curl-with-variables) ?

Comment: The "$RES" will be sent to `curl` as ***one*** argument, not four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array as in the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/656917/332764) to your previous question:

```
read -rp 'Write your query ' -a RES
curl -X POST "${RES[@]}" http://all.api.radio-browser.info/json/stations/search
```

Enter your arguments without single quotes since they are saved literally into the array, i.e. use

```
-d tag=jazz -d state=queensland
```